# Android Oreo time sensitive background work

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler

When migrating my app that needs to do time sensitive background work to Oreo i encountered a problem following the Migration Guide:

Pre Oreo I used a Service started by `Alarmmanager.setAndAllowWhileIdle` to shedule my work to always run within a few minutes of the sheduled time. Now, with Oreo, I am no longer allowed to start a service in the background. As far as I have red, the suggestion is to replace the service with a broadcast reciver if possible or use a to scheduled job.

I can't use a broadcast reciver because the work I want to do in the background may take longer than 10 seconds in rare cases.

I also do not think that I can use a scheduled job, because it is not guranteed to run withing a few minutes of the sheduled time if the device is in doze mode.

As it is really important for my app to run the service at that time, to collect some data that is associated with the time it is recoreded at, I somehow need a way to accomplish that task with Oreo background limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, with Oreo, i am no longer allowed to start a service in the background

Sure you are. Use `startForegroundService()`, or `getForegroundService()` as a `PendingIntent`. Have those point to a foreground `Service`, where you display a `Notification` via `startForeground()`.

Comment: It is not realy a case where the user wants to see an notification while the Service is running. While the user is aware of the app running in the background, he would not want to know when exactly it does because that is irrelevant to the user. Also, most of the time the Service would only run for a fraction of a second, and that notification appearing and instantly disappearing would not look good.

Comment: @Ben: "It is not realy a case where the user wants to see an notification while the Service is running" -- the user is welcome to block this notification channel.

Comment: Oh right I did not think of that possibility thank you